# Activity Life Cycle and database

Tags: android, lifecycle

I have an application that reads values from a Database table (Database is named SoftCopyDatabase) and populates a List with the values read from Database. On clicking an item from the list a New Activity Starts.

The problem is when I press the back key I got an error

```
          IllegalStateException: database already closed
```

My code is as follows:

public class OpenClick extends ListActivity {

```
public static String subjectName;
private SoftCopyDatabase lectures;
private static int[] subTO = { R.id.subject };
private static String[] subFROM = { SUBJECT };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lectures = new SoftCopyDatabase(this);

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    try {
        Cursor cursor = getSubjects();
        showSubjects(cursor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    lectures = new SoftCopyDatabase(this);

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    lectures.close();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    lectures.close();
}
//remaining code....
```

}

One point I would like to mention is if I remove the onStop() Method the application is working properly. But I have to include onstop() because I want to control the opening and closing of Database.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good article covering the topic:

http://awiden.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/database-mangement-and-the-activity-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

That's normal because both methods are executed... just do this on both methods (`onDestroy` and `onStop`):

```
if(lectures.isOpen()){
    lectures.close();
}
```

Although I think you can just put a `.close` invokation in one of them. Make sure to create the `isOpen` method in your `SoftCopyDatabase` class which must call the `SqliteDatabase` object's `isOpen` method.

Comment: hmm..ok...I will add it. But when I have included onRestart() method which is creating a new instant of DataBase, then why Database is not being created on returning to this Activity and why is this error shown?

Comment: First: why is the error shown? That is shown when you try to do something to your database (accessing it or closing it), but it has already been closed. Simple, eh? And with regards to the `onRestart` it is a bad idea to have the initialization there. `onRestart` is always called after `onCreate`, so you are creating two instances of the class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Ahan, I got your point. Actually at some Later part in my application an error stating dataBase already opened is Shown. To solve that error I used onStop and closed the Database. This solved the Database already Opened error, but introduces this one. 
What i actually want to know is there any method by which i can reopen the Database as soon as I return to this Activity.?

Comment: And the activity life cycle reference shows that it is onStart called just after onCreate, not onRestart, which is called after onStop.