# When is recommendable to open and close a database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing an app using a database but I don't know when is useful close it?

Is recommended close each time or I should keep opened until I app will close?

Thank you

Comment: answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125755/activity-life-cycle-and-database which leads to great article here: http://awiden.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/database-mangement-and-the-activity-lifecycle/

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using `ContentProvider`. It also makes it easy to handle database and data from many Activities and Fragments. You also takes minimum effort to handle db connection

Comment: I agree, content providers are the way to go. I have done a lot of apps with services and activities connecting to the database at the same time. Content providers handle all the connections and ensure that there are no lock issues associated with file lock on the database when two separate threads try to access the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity do :

```
public static DataBaseConect db=null; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db=new DataBaseConect(this);}

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
         db.close();
    }
```

Comment: yup , (y) .. bro : put this code in the main activity (the activity wish lunch the app ) ...

Comment: DataBaseConect is a class ok

Answer (score 0):

Close the database when your Activity is destroyed.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

//close db in here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use a connection pool, eg Apache commons-dbcp http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ and close ResultSet, Statement and Connection immediately after use.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the architecture of your code.
Connections are basically opened at DAO layer and the code to close a connection should be in 'finally' block.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the database takes a finite amount of time. It's negligible when connecting over a domain socket or named pipe, but it can be much larger if over a network connection, or worse yet, the open Internet. Leave it connected for the life of the request at least. And at the end you should always close it, at times it will be implicitly done when the program terminates but its a good practice to keep a check.

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus is that you close the database connection after you have finished using it.

For example this could be after using the connection only once on start up, you would close it after that initial use.

You may want to use the database connection again, however, in which case you should leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

It will be always advisable to open and close the connection for each query operation....sometimes user may take time to send request and keeping database connection open for log time is not advisable. In java you can use "Finally" block for connection closing method call, In C u can use destructor to call connection close method...or explicitly when u done with query execution